# Tableview cells not resizing properly to content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

For some strange reason the TableView Cells are not fitting the dynamic textual content properly. They should have a slight margin between the top and bottom of cell. Unfortunately, depending on the amount of textual content, some cells have no top and bottom margin(tightly packed) and others have huge margins.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    float result = 30;
    if (indexPath.section != 0){

        CGSize size = [[self textForIndexPath:indexPath isTitle:NO] sizeWithFont:kITDescriptionFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(220, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        result = MAX(result, size.height);
    }

    return result;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *doubleCellIdentifier = @"ITDoubleDetailCEllIdentifier";
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ITDetailCEllIdentifier";


    NSString *cellIdent = (indexPath.section == 0)? doubleCellIdentifier : cellIdentifier;
    ITDescriptionCell *cell = (ITDescriptionCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdent];
    if (!cell) {
        UITableViewCellStyle style = (indexPath.section == 0)? UITableViewCellStyleValue2 : UITableViewCellStyleDefault;
        cell = [[ITDescriptionCell alloc] initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:cellIdent];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        [cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
        [cell.textLabel setFont:kITDescriptionFont];
    }
    else {
        [cell.textLabel setText:@""];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setText:@""];
    }

    [cell sizeToFit];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing [cell sizeToFit]?

Comment: Do you have problems with your cell resizing or your text/detail label.

Comment: @Adithya Yes I've tried that, no difference.

Comment: @kushyar I have problems with Cell resizing only

Comment: Are you using background image in your ITDescriptionCell. If set it's autoReasize property. I think the problem is in your cell, check and set all its subViews autoResize property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically calculate the height of your text and based on that and the padding you want, adjust the height of the cell through the following delegate method:

```
#define PADDING 10.0f
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)t heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Subscription *sub = [_dictTask valueForKeyPath:@"subscription"];

    NSArray *meta = sub.meta.allObjects;

    NSString *text = [[meta objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"sum_value"];
    CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width - PADDING * 3, 1000.0f)];

    return textSize.height + PADDING * 3;
}
```